Generating enum types with Hasura & @graphql-codegen
I'm using Hasura cloud to expose data from a PostgreSQL table.
My frontend is a Next.js app where I have configured graphql-codegen to type my queries:
{
    schema: {
      [process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HASURA_BASE_URL]: {
        headers: {
          'X-Hasura-Admin-Secret': '****',
          'X-Hasura-Role': 'public',
        },
      },
    },
    documents: [
      './shared/**/*.tsx',
    ],
    ignoreNoDocuments: true,
    generates: {
      [`./shared/__generated/gql/`]: {
        preset: 'client',
        config: {
          avoidOptionals: true,
          skipTypename: false,
          scalars: {
            bigint: 'number',
            citext: 'string',
          },
        },
        presetConfig: {
          fragmentMasking: false,
        },
      },
    },
  }

This works like a charm except one point: all scalars coming from DB types are typed as "any". The generated file look like this:
export type Scalars = {
  ID: { input: string; output: string; }
  String: { input: string; output: string; }
  Boolean: { input: boolean; output: boolean; }
  Int: { input: number; output: number; }
  Float: { input: number; output: number; }
  AggregateName: { input: any; output: any; }
  BrandRating: { input: any; output: any; }
  CheckoutStatus: { input: any; output: any; }
  CollectionType: { input: any; output: any; }
  ...
}

At this point, I don't know how I should type those. Any idea on how to do it?
I tried to follow documentation about Enum resolvers:
enumValues: {
   Color: './enums#ColorsCode'
}

but I don't want to duplicate all enums definitions here.

Just found this issue: https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/982.
It looks like Hasura does not implement GraphQL enums...
